# Rule for when to use "could" as a helper?

Tags: grammaticality, modal-verbs, subjunctive-mood, conditionals

> It would be helpful if you could provide us further details.

Is the use of *could* wrong here? Should it be

> It would be helpful if you provide us further details.

What is the rule when should we just stick to the present form without any helping verb?

Comment: I edited your title to make it more descriptive and inserted what I think is the example of how you think the sentence should be phrased.  If you don't like these edits, you may edit the question yourself to rollback my edits.

Comment: definitely it's more descriptive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Could" here acts as a "buffer word" - a word which is not grammatically necessary, but which adds a sort of tentative quality, which softens the request and makes it feel more polite.

It could be readily replaced by "would" or "were to" - all softening the bald request by adding a tentative quality. ("It would be helpful" is already doing this, relative to "Provide us further details", which would be very peremptory).

Without the "could", it still needs a bit of attention because the tenses are wrong: with the condition "would", you need a past form (historically, a past subjunctive, but that's irrelevant today) in the main clause, so:

> It would be helpful if you provided us further details.

Alternatively without the conditional:

> It will be helpful if you provide us further details.

Comment: very nicely done!